# how do i resize my form input field

Tags: php, css, html

I just want to resize my form input useing textarea but I could not get a better output this my code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="signupform">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Sign Up</legend>

      <label for="name">message</label>
      <textarea input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Enter  your message" cols="20" rows="20" required value="<?php if($error) echo $message; ?>" </span>
    </div>
    
    <label for="name">number</label>
    <textarea input type="text" name="number" placeholder="input number" cols="20" rows="20" required value="<?php if($error) echo $number; ?>" </
    textarea></span>
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" name="signup" value="Sign Up" />
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form></body>
</html>
```

big thanks in advance

Comment: please can you edit with code example?

Comment: you didn't closed your textarea opened tag and value should be inside open and closed tags. To resize change rows and cols value. briefly explained in answer.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't closed your textarea opened tag properly.

Change your `rows` and `cols` attribute values for updating `height` and `width`.

Example:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="70">
```

`rows` for `height` and `cols` for `width`

And value should be inside textarea open and closed tag as:

```
<textarea input type="text" name="number" placeholder="input number" cols="70" rows="4" required>
    <?php if($error) echo $number; ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: my placeholder=" text " do not live on click why?

Comment: placeholder do not hide just on click. it just gets hide when you type something in your textarea

Answer (score 1):

Textarea doesn't have value attribute...

Provide value like this

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="signupform">
            <fieldset>
                <div>
                    <legend>Sign Up</legend>
                    <label for="name">message</label>
                    <textarea input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Enter  your message" cols="20" rows="20" required><?php if($error) echo $message; ?></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="name">number</label>
                    <textarea input type="text" name="number" placeholder="input number" cols="20" rows="20" required ><?php if($error) echo $number; ?></textarea>
                </div>
                <div><input type="submit" name="signup" value="Sign Up" /></div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```